# How can i create a complex keyboard style , (such as containing a list view)?

Tags: android, keyboard

I have googled a lot but still don't find an answer.

I want to create a keyboard style like this:

[image]

You see that the left most keys are in a special column and it can be scrolled when my finger move up and down.

How should I write my keyboard layout and inflate it in java code ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public View onCreateInputView()` returns any kind of View you can create.

```
LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
View v = li.inflate(R.layout.myview, null);
```

where *getLayoutInflater()* is defined in InputMethodService.

Note also there is [*onEvaluateFullscreenMode()*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#FullscreenMode)

-- UPDATE: I am pasting a portion of xml that is not related to the original question but related to the question asked in a comment below (statelist drawable for a Layout working as a button):

drawable/button_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bbg_pressed"></item>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bbg_selected"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bbg_normal"></item>
</selector>
```

the drawables are 9-patch:

```
myproject/res/drawable$ ls bbg*
bbg_normal.9.png  bbg_pressed.9.png  bbg_selected.9.png
```

Comment: You can use as a button a LinearLayout or any other view with `android:clickable=true`

Comment: yes, I did. when i click the button , the "click" event is triggered correctly. But the button's background doesn't change at all. As i remember, there should be a default statelist drawable for button widget. Do you know why?

Comment: I think, because this is how changing background is implemented. See example code in the update.

Comment: Appreciate your help !